# dialog.dispose() causes screen flickering on Android

Tags: android, codenameone

I have an issue with screen flickering after `dialog.dispose()` on Android (that doesn't happen on iOS)

Here is the video (please watch in 480p, as YouTube drops frames in lower resolutions)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YExvPno3hjc

Here is the code for Dialog

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Shop");
TableLayout dialogLayout = new TableLayout(buttons.length, 4);

dialog.setName("ShopDialog");
dialog.setLayout(dialogLayout);
dialog.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(true);
```

then TableLayout gets filled with labels and buttons, including "Close" button

```
Button.setCapsTextDefault(false);
Button closeButton = new Button ("Close");
closeButton.getAllStyles().setFgColor(WordsSynonyms.UI_TEXT_COLOR);
closeButton.getAllStyles().setBgImage(theme.getImage("button.png"));
closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        dialog.dispose();               
    }
});         
Button.setCapsTextDefault(true);
```

and finally gets shown like this

```
dialog.showPacked(BorderLayout.CENTER, true);
```

The problem is, if I tap "Close" button the whole screen flickers,
it looks like very brief appearance of black rectangle that covers Form, 
but it doesn't happen if you tap out of dialog, it disappears normally

I have tried to change Form tint to white `setTintColor(0x3fffffff)`, to check if it's somehow related to the tint, but looks like it doesn't, there is still black flickering, although Form tint is set to 25% white

This happens on three different Forms, with different dialogs, so this should be something more general, it wasn't like that before, but the only things I have changed at global level is build hints for iOS, which shouldn't have an effect on Android

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a performance issue with the background form or an EDT violation. In Android we paint the screen asynchronously and if we miss a frame this can happen. You might be able to alleviate the problem by removing dialog transitions using the theme constants:

```
dialogTransitionIn=empty
dialogTransitionOut=empty
```

But it might be caused because an element of the form takes too long to paint. Open the form in the simulator and fill it to a level that shows the problem (without opening the dialog). Then in the performance monitor tool refresh the tree and inspect the paint operations required to draw the form. See if something stands out as expensive.

Comment: Hi @Shai, `dialogTransitionIn=empty` and `dialogTransitionOut=empty` are already there, I had to turn off transitions for Form and Dialog because of performance issues on old Android phones. 
Regarding Form perfomance issues, there were indeed some issues with roudned buttons, but I have replaced button faces with images, these rounded buttons are in fact png images (1-10KB in size)
The only big images in Form background, 100KB, 1080x2048, `Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED`

Comment: Removing background and button images didn't helped, Form still flickers after `dialog.dispose()` called in `ActionListener`. For some reason this doesn't happen if I tap outside of dialog, although the same `dialog.dispose()` called but in this case in `pointerReleased` method of Dialog class

Comment: Do you see anything in the console when you draw? It's possible there's an issue in the device in this case and it prints something to the log. Another test you can do is wrap the content of the actionListener of the button with a callSerially to defer it to the next round of the EDT. That might workaround the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Shai, there is no errors in app log, but wrapping the content of the actionListener with callSerially worked, no more screen flickering, how I can accept this as correct ? Could you edit original answer to include callSerially ?

Comment: The button release issues a repaint that might be colliding with the button dispose repaint in some way.

Comment: look like that, anyway wrapping ActionListner content with callSerially  helped me, please edit your original answer to include that info